# task: Prime numbers in function

Tags: python, python-3.8

help me please.

Write a function: User enters natural numbers A and B (A <B).  The function prints all prime numbers separated by a space on the segment [A, B]

This is my code but it doesn't work, wrong output, I don't understand why?

```
def prime_numbers(a, b):
   for i in range(a, b + 1):
      dividers = 0
      for j in range (2, i):
         if i % j == 0:
             dividers += 1

         if dividers == 1:
             return i
a = int (input ("Enter first number: ")
b = int (input ("Enter second number: ")
print (prime_numbers (a, b))
```

When this code is e.g. ran with `a=5` and `b=11` I expect the output to be `5 7 11`. Instead the output is `6`.

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Please post a [mre] of your code ***as text*** and also explain your problem. *"it doesn't work"* doesn't give us any indication of the problem. Do you get an error? Wrong output? Please read about [ask]

Comment: I edit my question

Answer (score 0):

### Problems with Logic

The function you wrote is meant to calculate how many dividers are **in** the numbers from a-b, which is different than what the prompt is asking.

You're on the right track with the loops and the `%` (mod) if statement, but you're off by a bit. In order to calculate the number of prime numbers, there are through a-b, you're going to have to do something different because right now I think your code is calculating the number of divisors there are for numbers a-b.

### Problems with Code

When you use the keyword `return`, you return a value for the entire function and considering you're calculating for multiple prime numbers, I don't think that'd work out well.

Also, I'd be sure to watch out for proper tabbing, your tabbing is inconsistent, and sometimes you've used spaces, sometimes you've used tabs. Python doesn't use brackets (languages such as C, C++, Java, JavaScript aren't reliant on tabs) and is reliant on consistent spacing/tabbing.

Don't forget to close the brackets for the `int()` function, which is meant to convert a string to an integer.

I think what you meant to do is this:

```py
def prime_numbers(a, b):
    primes = [] # Make a list of primes
    for i in range(a, b + 1): # Iterate from a-b
        if is_prime(i): # Check if the number is a prime or not
            primes.append(i) # If it is a prime, then add it to the list
    return primes # Return the prime list

def is_prime(v): # Function to check for prime numbers
    for x in range(2, v): # Iterate from 2 to the input value
        if v % x == 0: # Check if v is divisible by x 
            return False # If it is divisible by x, return False becaues it's not a prime number 
    return True # Haven't found any divisors for the number, so return True.

a = int (input ("Enter first number: "))
b = int (input ("Enter second number: "))
print (prime_numbers (a, b))
```

I'd suggest you use websites such as YouTube and W3Schools to get a better understanding of how to code and remember, **GOOGLE IS YOUR FRIEND**.

Edit: My apologies, the tabbing issue was caused due to my IDE (Sublime), but it's still a good thing to keep in mind when working with Python.